# Recover application installation parameters from MDT deployment

Tags: deployment, mdt

I used MDT to deploy Windows 7 with a bunch of applications. After a hard-drive failure, I no longer have the original deployment directory and have lost everything. I do, however, have the USB key which was used for installations and have all the application packages sat in the Deploy/Applications directory.

Is there anywhere I can look to find the command-line parameters that were configured for each installation? I've searched all the files in the Scripts directory but found nothing. Where does LiteTouch look to find information on the available packages and installation parameters? I'll have to start from scratch but was hoping not to have to hunt around for the necessary silent options.

Comment: Looks like you have your answer at the [TechNet Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mdt/thread/bf122895-591c-4a81-ac17-21520070ba10). Are you all set now?

Answer (score 1):

MDT stores the syntax for application installs in `\\server\share$\control\applications.xml` file.

A UFD should have the syntax in the `\deploy\control\applicatons.xml` file.

Regardless of where the xml file exists, you'll want to find it and use Notepad++ or something to do a mass find and replace of the useless info and get it cleaned up. That way you have a "cheat sheet" of the command line syntax you've used. I've done this so I can just copy and paste back into a new deployment share when need be.

There's even a remote chance that MDT may even allow you to mount the USB as a share as well. That way you may be able to drag and drop apps from the USB back into a new share.